# "log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly" error

Tags: java, log4j

I have a web application, in which one of the JSPs contain:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(System.getenv("MY_HOME") + "/cfg/log4j.properties");
```

I double-checked that `MY_HOME` is setup

The Tomcat web server says:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mycompany.data.JobData).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

The same setup works fine in one of the other servers.

Any hints?

**The problem is that no logs are created**

Comment: Have you considered moving the initialization logic to either a filter or a full fledged servlet's initialization phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PropertyConfigurator must be called before anything in your system attempts to log to avoid this warning. You may find setting the log4j configuration on the command line more reliable.

Or you could ignore the warning. ;)

BTW: You don't want to call this method too often, ideally only once.

Comment: Why would the exact same setup work in different environment?

Comment: The startup could be different such that it doesn't log anything before this line is called. The setup might be almost the same but a different OS/JVM version/CPU/Disk speed could make the difference as to what order things start.

Comment: The setup is almost certain to be different in this case. 2 environments were set up by different people and exist in different countries. How would you troubleshoot something like this?

Comment: @mac, change the systems incrementally until the problem goes away. Or you could write your application/setup your environment so it doesn't matter how the systems startup.  Do you see any logs missing in the system which produces the warning?  Does the class it complains about log any critical information?

Comment: The only observable effect is that no log files are produced at all at this point. To make sure problem is not PATH related, i'll put in a full path and try again.. If something else occurs at you - please let me know

Answer (score 2):

Not related to your answer, but this helps too.

If it's a web application, the easiest way is to make sure that your `log4j.properties` is situated in `WEB-INF/classes` folder in your `WAR` file. When your application will be deployed, log4J will be configured.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, its helps to me.
http://www.log4j.ru/articles/HelloWorld.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to this problem running a Eclipse Dynamic Web Project in Apache Tomcat 6.  Bascially, you need to load the log4j properties file out of your context.

Two basic steps

(1) Get the log4j.properties file into the "class directory" of the war file.

(2) Read the log4j properties file out of the current context.  I found the best way to do this is to access the current thread's context and work from there.

For the first step above, alter the Eclipse build process to add an additional directory that will eventually load into the WEB-INF/classes directory in the war file. Specifically....

(1) In Eclipse, right click your project in the project explorer, select 'New'->'Folder'. You can name the folder anything, but the standard in this case is 'resources'. The new folder should appear at the root level of your project.

(2) Move the log4j.properties file into this new folder.

(3) Right click the project again, and select 'Build-Path'->'Configure Build Path'. Select the 'Sources' tab. Click the 'Add Folder' button. Browse to find your new folder you created in step (1) above. Select 'OK'.

(4) Once back to the eclipse Project Explorer view, note that the folder has now moved to the 'Java Resources' area (ie it's no longer at the root due to eclipse presentation abstraction).

(5) Clean build your project.

(6) To validate that the .properties file now exists in WEB-INF/classes in your war file, export a war file to an easy location (right click Project -> Export -> War file) and checkout the contents. Note that the log4j.properties file now appears in the WEB-INF/classes.

Now for the second step above, accessing the context to read the file.  Add the following code where attempting to read the file.  Note that this reads this out of the war file context, so this 'should' work as the war file moves from server to server.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties") );
```